# Getting property type with reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, gettype

I have a little problem by getting the type of an Property by reflection.

I have a class which include only simple types like string, int, decimal...

```
public class simple 
{
  public string article { get; set; }
  public decimal price { get; set; }
}
```

Now I need to take this properties by reflection and handle them by it's type.

I need something like this:

```
Type t = obj.GetType();
PropertyInfo propInfo = t.GetProperty("article");
Type propType = ??  *GetPropType*() ??

switch (Type.GetTypeCode(propType))
{
  case TypeCode.Decimal:
    doSome1;
    break;
  case TypeCode.String:
    doSome2;
    break;
}
```

For strings it works to do 
`propInfo.PropertyType.UnderlyingSystemType` as GetPropType() but not for decimal for example.

For decimal works `propInfo.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments.FirstOrDefault();` but not for strings.

Hos can get the type for all simple types?

Comment: Uh, `propInfo.PropertyType` should suffice. [Fiddle here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CuWdt0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `PropertyType` to determine which is `string` or `decimal`. Try like this;

```
Type t = obj.GetType();
PropertyInfo propInfo = t.GetProperty("article");
if (propInfo.PropertyType == typeof(string))
{
    Console.WriteLine("String Type");
}
if (propInfo.PropertyType == typeof(decimal) 
    || propInfo.PropertyType == typeof(decimal?))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Decimal Type");
}
```

Comment: I don't know why but the content of propInfo.PropertyType for my decimal property  is this:

propType = {Name = "Nullable`1" FullName = "System.Nullable`1[[System.Decimal, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]"}
                      
This is not like typeof(decimal) ?! Why?

Comment: @Nunzio your question code is incorrect then. Your code must have `decimal? price`, where the ? is really just syntatic sugar for `Nullable<decimal> price`

Comment: I guess, you defined the property as "decimal?" instead of "decimal". I updated the answer.

Comment: Oh, ok now I understood. Thank you very much.